# SKAction.moveTo not working at all

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skaction

I'm facing a strange problem with Sprite-kit and Swift 1.2. I have the following code. The `fingerSprite` appears correctly in the middle of the screen.

When I apply the `moveTo` action however, nothing happens. I'm quite new to Sprite-Kit and Swift so I might be doing something totally stupid but please bear with me.

What am I doing wrong?

```
   override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
tutorialStepReset()

var bounceLabels = SKAction.sequence([
    SKAction.scaleTo(1.3, duration: 0.5),
    SKAction.scaleTo(1.0, duration: 0.5)
    ])

var fingerPoint = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height/2)
var fingerSprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "finger.png")

switch tutorialGuideIndex {
    case 0: self.runAction( SKAction.runBlock({
        self.labelScore.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(bounceLabels))

    }))
    case 1: self.runAction( SKAction.runBlock({
        self.labelUntilNextLevel.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(bounceLabels))

    }))
    case 2: self.runAction( SKAction.runBlock({
        self.labelCurrentLevel.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(bounceLabels))

    }))
    case 3:


        fingerSprite.position = fingerPoint
        fingerSprite.zPosition = labelZPosition
        self.addChild(fingerSprite)
    case 4:
        //move finger & draw line
        fingerPoint.x = fingerPoint.x+20
        fingerPoint.y = fingerPoint.y+20
        fingerSprite.runAction(SKAction.scaleTo(2.0, duration: 4.0))
        fingerSprite.runAction(SKAction.moveTo(fingerPoint, duration: 4.0))


   tutorialGuideIndex++

}
```

Comment: where do you add the sprite to the containing node and when do you run the action? from your posted code the sprite is not added to any node ...

Comment: Good point giorashc! I refactored the example. Basically I'm working in touches began, method.

Comment: Post the whole method relating to fingerSprite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On each touch you create a `new` sprite and only in `case 3` you add it to the node **without** running the move action.

When reaching `case 4` you just run the action on the new sprite instance without adding it to the node so it will never be shown.

Use the move action right after adding the sprite to the node

```
   case 3:       
        fingerSprite.position = fingerPoint
        fingerSprite.zPosition = labelZPosition
        self.addChild(fingerSprite)

        fingerSprite.runAction(SKAction.moveTo(fingerPoint, duration: 4.0))
```

---

I also notice you  try to run two actions on the same sprite:

```
    fingerSprite.runAction(SKAction.scaleTo(2.0, duration: 4.0))
    fingerSprite.runAction(SKAction.moveTo(fingerPoint, duration: 4.0))
```

in order to run actions one after another you should you the sequence action:

```
fingerSprite.runAction(SKAction.sequence([
   SKAction.scaleTo(2.0, duration: 4.0),
   SKAction.moveTo(fingerPoint, duration: 4.0)]));
```

if you need these actions to run in parallel use the `group` action instead of `sequence`

Comment: Do you mean `group` not `spawn`?

Comment: nothing was stupid. a valid question we all asked ourselves at some point ;)

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was super simple. For some reason the sprites are paused and you have to set it to false.

```
newTile.isPaused = false
```